# Reduce javascript code

Tags: javascript, angular, oop

I have two functions in my angular project, one is `aceitaProposta` that does this:

```
aceitaProposta() {
    this.aceita();
    // some other code
}
```

and I have `recusaProposta`:

```
recusaProposta() {
    this.recusa();
    // some other code
}
```

Now, the only difference between `this.recusa` and `this.aceita` is that the first one increments a property and the second one decrement it. I want to know if there's a way that I can transform these two functions into one function only using something like `if` to identify if its decrementing or incrementing. This way I would call the same function in both `aceitaProposta` and `recusaProposta`. Example:

```
aceitaProposta() {
   this.incrementDecrement();
    // some other code
}

recusaProposta() {
    this.incrementDecrement();
    // some other code
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can pass a boolean to the function to indicate whether the value should be incremented or decremented.

Comment: `this.add(1)`, `this.add(-1)`.

Comment: Why do you need one function to do two different things? It's better to keep them separate instead of adding control flow to something that's supposed to be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KingFelix has it. Just pass a boolean.

```
incrementDecrement(shouldIncrement: boolean) {
  shouldIncrement ? value++ : value--;
}

aceitaProposta() {
    this.incrementDecrement(true);
}

recusaProposta() {
    this.incrementDecrement(false);
}
```

Comment: oh, that's it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Should be pretty easy.

```
function incrementDecrement(inc: boolean)
{
    inc ? this.prop++ : this.prop--;
}
```

Comment: Might as well be `this.prop += inc - !inc;` For clarity, use an `if`/`else` statement.

Comment: They've tagged the question with angular, so I think it's good to show a TypeScript answer here too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this uses ES6 and more 'functional' code. Make the parameter a function instead of a boolean. Then make the change in the function you pass.

```
update(alteration) {
    x = alteration(x);
}

aceitaProposta() {
    this.update((x) => x - 1);
}

recusalProposta() {
    this.update((x) => x + 1);
}
```

Without ES6 its a little ugly but you would just add in the anonymous function declarations.